# Duplicate get_header()

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Duplicate `get_header()` Problem!!!

I insert, using jQuery,  single-`{custom-post-type}.php` into an ajax container in my front-page. My single-`{custom-post-type}.php` use the wp function `get_header()` and my front-page is using `get_header()` to, so everything is already loaded. So when I load my custom posts It crash.

If I remove `get_header()` from my single-`{custom-post-type}.php` It loads okay into my front-page. But when I open in a new page nothing is loaded because I don't have my `header.php` to load all the styles, scripts, etc.

I already try with the conditional tags but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

I'm doing this:

In my frontpage I send the url using data-href

```
<a class="more-info" href="#" data-href="<?php echo the_permalink()?>" ></a>
```

Then in my javascript:

```
$( ".more-info" ).click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();  
    var page = $(this).attr('data-href'); 
    lateralAnimation.init(page);
});

init : function(page){              
    $('#ajax-inserted').load(page)   
}   

//#ajax-inserted is where I load the content in my frontpage.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your single-{custom-post-type}.php you could check for a query variable that you add on when you use jquery e.g "http://example.com/single-{custom-post-type}.php?isAjax=1"

Then in the php just do the following:

```
if(!isset($_GET['isAjax']) && $_GET['isAjax'] != 1)
{
   get_header();
}
```

Hope that answers your question.

**EDIT:** For the ajax call, if you are using .load(), then

```
$( "#divtoload" ).load( "single-{custom-post-type}.php?isAjax=1" );
```

Should do it

**EDIT 2:**
Try this then, this concatenates the variable to the url

```
$( ".more-info" ).click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();  
    var page = $(this).attr('data-href'); 
    lateralAnimation.init(page);
});

init : function(page){      
    //changed this line
    $('#ajax-inserted').load(page+"?isAjax=1)   
}   

//#ajax-inserted is where I load the content in my frontpage.
```

Alternatively

```
<a class="more-info" href="#" data-href="<?php echo the_permalink()?>?isAjax=1" ></a>
```

Comment: Ok that should work. Could you give me an example of how to add that variable? I'm using load() to insert the single-{custom-post-type}.php into my front-page

Comment: Do you mean to add the variable in the ajax call?  
Also if that answers your question, don't forget to mark it as answered!

Comment: Thanks but not work. I will esit my question to show you how I load the url

Comment: Great it's works great!!! Note to edit: add " at the end of load(). THANKS A LOT!!!